# IPA upload error

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, ios11, xcode8, xcode9-beta5

I updated my app for ios 11 using Xcode 9 beta 5.(Objective C app)

The app is running(with Xcode 8.3 as well as Xcode 9 beta) without any error even on the device.

Today, I have created a build using XCode 8.3 to upload on test-flight, Which is giving below error on uploading to iTunes.

> ERROR ITMS-90534: "Invalid Toolchain. New apps and app updates must be
>   built with the public (GM) versions of Xcode 6 or later, macOS, and
>   iOS SDK or later. Don't submit apps built with beta software including
>   beta macOS builds."

Note - I used Xcode 8.3 to archive and upload build not Xcode 9 beta

Please suggest any solution to fix this error.

Comment: it is Xcode 8.3 and Mac OS version 10.12.6.

Comment: Did you create any Storyboard using Xcode 9?

Comment: Also check Xcode Project (Document) Format version that should be Xcode 8.0-compatible only

Comment: Yes i've tried changing the Project format version too. But still having the same error.

Comment: Apple is not currently accepting any build with iOS 11.
[link](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/85984)

Comment: "The app is running(with Xcode 8.3 as well as Xcode 9 beta)" I wonder whether opening the project with Xcode 9 marked it in some way.

Answer (score 3):

> An error message it self says, Use stable (not beta) version of Xcode
>   to create a build.
>   Your mac OS should also be stable (not beta)

Use Xcode 8.3.3 to create your build and upload using Application Upload.

Ensure following checkpoints, while creating your build:

- Xcode version
- Mac OS version
- Xcode Project (Document) Format version (Xcode 8.0-compatible)

Comment: I am using XCode 8.3 and it is also a stable version.

Comment: Yeah after using 8.3.3 build has been uploaded to itunesConnect.
But it replies with an error:

Comment: Yeah after using 8.3.3 build has been uploaded to iTunes connect.
But it replies with an error:
> invalid iOS SDK
look like apple is not currently accepting any build with version iOS 11

Comment: Yes,according app store guidelines, they do not accept beta version app or support for beta version.

Answer (score 0):

We can submit the build for testing iOS 11 related changes using Xcode 9 beta 6 version. 
refer to the below link :-

https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/85984

But for store distribution, you have to wait until Xcode 9 (GM) version is not released.
For reference :-

https://www.reddit.com/r/iOSProgramming/comments/6wq7go/when_will_we_be_able_to_submit_ios_11_app/

Answer (score -1):

10.12.6 is a fifth beta of macOS Sierra.

An error message it self says, Use stable (not beta) version of Xcode to create a build. Your mac OS should also be stable (not beta)

Comment: Dear Dhruv - This link says 10.12.6 is stable version of Sierra (https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/macos-sierra/id1127487414?mt=12&l=en-gb&ls=1)

Comment: 10.12.6 is latest macOS Sierra version update https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1930?locale=en_US